# select all rows where date is equal to current date

Tags: php, mysql, date

We have a  table with a time stamp column, we want to fetch all rows which were posted today or we can say timestamp = curdate(). how can we do that using a MySQL query?

thanks for your support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(yourcolumn) = CURDATE()
```

This will fetch all records where `yourcolumn` is today, not taking time into account.